# Converting randomly generating random id in PHP into uniqueidentifier in mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, database

i have to genrate automatic session id using uniqid() in php but i have to store it in MSSQL database.but i cannot convert it type of uniqueidentifier.

```
<?php

//set the random id length 
$random_id_length = 10; 

//generate a random id encrypt it and store it in $rnd_id 
$rnd_id = crypt(uniqid(rand(),1)); 

//to remove any slashes that might have come 
$rnd_id = strip_tags(stripslashes($rnd_id)); 

//Removing any . or / and reversing the string 
$rnd_id = str_replace(".","",$rnd_id); 
$rnd_id = strrev(str_replace("/","",$rnd_id)); 

//finally I take the first 10 characters from the $rnd_id 
$rnd_id = substr($rnd_id,0,$random_id_length); 

echo "Random Id: $rnd_id" ;
echo "<br>";

?>
```

this is the code now i want this $rnd_id into uniqueidentifier type and store it into mssql database

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it this way. Better let MSSQL assign a unique id and get this one after you saved the table row. This way you can be sure your ids are really unique (in the scope of you db).

```
$qry = mssql_query("INSERT INTO tbl(...) VALUES(...) SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID=@@IDENTITY");
$res = mssql_fetch_assoc($qry);
```

`$res['LAST_INSERT_ID']` will hold the last insert id.